# django-Ajax Does not work on some button clicks

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

Iam having a webpage which contains Multiple Buttons Generated using django.Using ajax,When I click a button the is value send to server randomly.The button value is set according to value passed through context from django.Heres's the Code:

```
<button name="date" type="submit" value={{d}} ">
```

Ajax Code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
     function sendData(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
     type : "POST", 
     url: "",
     data: {
       date : event.target.value,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',

     },
     success: function(data){
             
            },
     
            failure: function() {
                
            }

      });
    }
  </script>
```

When i try to print the request.POST on views.py it sometimes show only csrftoken instead of both date and csrftoken,I have tried giving alert box in the success function and alert always pops up when i click a button even though only csrf token is passed to server
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the job done

```
<button type="submit" onclick="return sendData('{{d}}')">
  <p>{{y}}</p>
  <p class="card-text">{{d}}</p>
</button>
```

I've removed some code you can add it later

```
function sendData(date){
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST", 
    url: "",
    data: {
      date : date,
      csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}',
    },
    
    success: function(data){
      
    },
    failure: function() {
      
    }
    
  });
  return false
}
```

I'll suggest not to use **id** inside loop because it repeates same **id** multiple times

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
> value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's
> for more info check [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem.
But your solution works 6/10 times.Sometimes it will get the data to backend but sometimes it wont.

Comment: Hello @achu1 can you [edit] your quetion and put updated code

Comment: i have updated code and my question

Comment: Hello @achu1 I'll sugeest not use ``button`` tag to send data use input then it will give acurate values I guess

Comment: Hello @achu1 check I've edited my answer let me know if it works.

Comment: hey,Thanks for your help,it works for now,and your code need some changes,
it should be `onclick="return sendData('{{d}}')` instead of `onclick="sendData({{d}})"` and should return false at end of `senddata()` so that page wont reload,Please update your code and i will accept the answer

Comment: And i found a weird thing,by giving `onclick="sendData({{d}})"` like u said and when i log date in ajax body it show `2012 2013` for each button click.but my dictionary contains only `{'2022-01-08': 'Sat', '2022-01-09': 'Sun', '2022-01-10': 'Mon'}` and no trace `2012 or 2013`,dont know whats going on

Comment: I've added info in my answer as you mentioned and about wong output you can inspect your code in browser to check what kind of value function receving.